# Number formatting in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a dynamically changing input reading from a file. The numbers are either `Int` or `Double`. Why does Scala print `.0` after every `Double` number? Is there a way for Scala to print it the same way it reads it?

Example:

```
var x:Double = 1
println (x)             // This prints '1.0', I want it to print '1'
x = 1.0                 // This prints '1.0', which is good
```

I can't use `Int` because some of the input I get are `Double`s. I can't use `String` or `AnyVal` because I perform some math operations.

Thank you,

Answer (score 30):

```
scala> "%1.0f" format 1.0
res3: String = 1
```

If your input is either `Int` or `Double`, you can do it like this:

```
def fmt(v: Any): String = v match {
  case d : Double => "%1.0f" format d
  case i : Int => i.toString
  case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> fmt(1.0)
res6: String = 1

scala> fmt(1)
res7: String = 1

scala> fmt(1.0f)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at .fmt(<console>:7)
        at .<init>(<console>:6)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at RequestResult$.<init>(<console>:4)
        at RequestResult$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at RequestResult$result(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.Dele...
```

Otherwise, you might use `BigDecimals`. They are slow, but they do come with the scale, so "1", "1.0" and "1.00" are all different:

```
scala> var x = BigDecimal("1.0")
x: BigDecimal = 1.0

scala> x = 1
x: BigDecimal = 1

scala> x = 1.0
x: BigDecimal = 1.0

scala> x = 1.000
x: BigDecimal = 1.0

scala> x = "1.000"
x: BigDecimal = 1.000
```

Comment: That's awful. You just threw all type safety out the window. The easiest way is to do:
    n.toInt.toString

Comment: @juancn How did I throw type safety out of the window? By the way, "`var n = 1.0; n.toInt.toString`" produces `1`, not `1.0` as desired.

Comment: The thing is that in `fmt` you're stating that you accept 'Any' which is in fact not true, because you throw an IllegalArgumentException if I pass, say, a String. You could do something like: `def fmt[T <% math.ScalaNumericConversions](n : T) = 
 if(n.toInt == n) n.toInt.toString else n.toString` which is safe.
Illegal argument exceptions should be thrown only if the type system cannot express a reasonable set of constraints (for example, scala does not allow you to specify ranged integers as types).

Comment: Yes, my first comment is a bit cryptic, and it does not produce the desired result.

Comment: @joancn Oh, that. There's a way to restrict it to just `Int` and `Double`, though that's stuff for another question (which exists). But note that this particular solution is meant for when the input is either `Int` or `Double`.

Comment: @juancn you may use `AnyVal` instead of `Any` -- this will prohibit `String` at compile time and will provide better typesafety

Comment: I agree with @joancn in that this answer promotes forgoing static type safety by doing type checking at runtime.

Comment: @ErikAllik It is in the premise of the question that the type is only known at runtime. You could make an `Either[Int, Double]` instead of passing an `Any`, but that only means the code that, at runtime, distinguish between an `Int` and a `Double` is elsewhere.

Answer (score 8):

```
var x:Double = 1
var y:Double = 1.0

print(x) // => 1.0
print(y) // => 1.0
```

If i understand you question you want scala to print x and y differently? The problem is that x and y are both a variable of the type Double and look the same.

Why do you explicitly define the type of the vars?

```
var x = 1 
var y= 1.0

print(x) // => 1
print(y) // => 1.0
```

Comment: He said "dynamically changing input reading from a file". He's bringing numbers in, and the numbers may either be integer or not (but always stored as a Double).

Answer (score 6):

Use `printf`:

```
printf("The value is %.0f", x)
```

For a description of the format string, see [this page](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) from the Java SE 6 API documentation.

Note that you can ofcourse also use the Java library from Scala, so other ways to format numbers from Java can also be used from Scala. You can for example use class `java.text.DecimalFormat`:

```
val df = new java.text.DecimalFormat("#####")
println(df.format(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply

But the problem is that the number is unknown, either it is '1' or '1.0'. If it '1' I want to print '1', if it is '1.0' then I want to print '1.0'. But since it is Double, Scala always prints is as '1.0'

Comment: If you want that, you'll need to store it as a string. A `double` doesn't remember whether or not you assigned it with `1` or `1.0`.

Comment: Kodo, numbers do not inherently have a number of digits. There is no difference between a number that has the value 1 and a number that has the value 1.0.

Comment: @Jesper, you are correct, they have same value. The only problem is during printing and displaying it to human. If they put '1 + 1' they expect '2' not '2.0'

Comment: @JorgeOrtiz Do not pass scala.math.BigDecimal to a java.text.NumberFormat. The java class run several "instanceof" to check the type of the number, and obviously doesn't know about the wrapper. If anything use df.format(bigDecimal.underlying())

Answer (score 5):

Starting with Scala 2.10 you can use [the `f` interpolator](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html):

```
scala> val x: Double = 1
x: Double = 1.0

scala> println(f"$x%.0f")
1

scala> val i = 1
i: Int = 1

scala> println(f"$i%.0f")
1
```

Comment: The asker wants to format conditionally on how many decimal places the original number had.

Answer (score 4):

The use of a "_.0" at the end of floating point numbers is a convention. Just a way to know that the number is actually floating point and not an integer.

If you **really** need to "to print it the same way it reads it" you may have to rethink the way your code is structured, possibly preserving your input data. If it's just a formatting issue, the easiest way is to convert the values to integers before printing:

```
val x = 1.0
println(x.toInt)
```

If some are integers and some are not, you need a bit more code:

```
def fmt[T <% math.ScalaNumericConversions](n : T) = 
                    if(n.toInt == n) n.toInt.toString else n.toString

val a : Double = 1.0
val b : Double = 1.5
val c : Int = 1

println(fmt(a))
println(fmt(b))
println(fmt(c))
```

The code above should print:

```
1
1.5
1
```

The signature of the `fmt` method accepts any type that either is a subtype of `ScalaNumericConversions` or can be converted to one through implicit conversions (so we can use the `toInt` method).

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with a `Double` and want to format it as a `String` without `.0` when it's a whole number and with its decimals otherwise, then you could use [`String::stripSuffix`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#stripSuffix(suffix:String):String):

```
x.toString.stripSuffix(".0")
// val x: Double = 1.34    =>   "1.34"
// val x: Double = 1.0     =>   "1"
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer to this question. EDIT: @juancn 's answer is correct too, but much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Use type inference, rather than explicit typing.

```
scala> val xi = 1
xi: Int = 1

scala> val xd = 1.0
xd: Double = 1.0

scala> println(xi)
1

scala> println(xd)
1.0
```

Comment: Ooops sorry this is a duplicate answer.