# Convertig the result of collect() from E+ format to Double

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to save the result of RDD.collect() to a text file but the metric part of the result is coming in E+ format as below

```
res78: Array[(String, Double)] = Array((xyz,1.013764394670889E13))
```

Is there a way to convert this to decimal ? I am using scala

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number formatting in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350566/number-formatting-in-scala)

Comment: you can use Java Bigdecimal library http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.math.BigDecimal